# Touch event in phonegap application

Tags: cordova, touch

In my phonegap application I have some touch area that I want to marked them when user touches enters them(even if touch stated out sid of the area and then enters the touch area).
I used touchmoved but this event trigger when touch move in the same element that it started then I tried touchenter event but it didn't trigger at all.

here is my code to add listener:

```
var c=document.getElementById("spans");
newSpan.addEventListener("touchenter", Over, false);
```

which event I should use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse and touch events don't usually work that way, but if you attach an event to the document rather than the target area, you should be able to track all touches and check if their locations match your target elements.

Comment: Yeah this is the solution that I want to use at last if I can't find any other one.